# Como verificar se os campos do vetor sao nulos?

Tags: java, array, string, matriz

Estou construindo um programa, o qual deverá verificar inicialmente se o array do tipo (Classe) é nulo.
A minha classe possui o método get e set, assim como os construtores com e sem padrão.
Porém, quando o programa inicializa, os valores de cada célula do meu array deverão ser nulas para o preenchimento ordenado dos dados.

Mas é justamente nesse ponto que onde acontece o erro.

Se eu colocar que o meu `vetor[i] == null`, o programa pula para o final e não executa o comando.

Para o comando executar estou colocando `vetor[i] != null`, mas desta forma estou sobrescrevendo alguns dados.

Como resolvo?

```
public void Insere(){

    for( int  i = 0; i < estacionamento.length;i++){

          estacionamento[i] = new Veiculo();

        if(estacionamento[i] != null){

         estacionamento[i].setPlaca(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("informe a placa do veiculo"));
         estacionamento[i].setModelo(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("informe o modelo do veiculo"));



        }else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " não ha vagas no estacionamento");
        } break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Por que tem um `break` ali no final?

Comment: Está um pouco complicado entender o que deseja. Inclusive porque term esse `if`, até pode ter um motivo. Existe casos que a criação do `Veiculo` falhar? Tem motivo para isto? Me parece que há erros conceituais antes de erros de execução neste código.

Comment: O codigo por completo compila sem problema algum! Entretanto na claisula if se executo da forma que esta ele pula para a parte apos o else.O que não é correto uma vez que o array estacionamento se encontra vazio. O unico jeito que encontrei (incorreto) é colocao o estacionamento[i] != null...... Desta forma ele lê e executa como quero. Mas me permite colocar quantos objetos quiser sobrescrevendo os ja existentes

Comment: O break; do final é para a queda de comando e retorno do menu principal que esta na classe main

Answer (score 0):

Suas intenções com o código estão confusas.

> A minha classe possui o método get e set, assim como os construtores com e sem padrão. Porém, quando o programa inicializa, os valores de cada célula do meu array deverão ser nulas para o preenchimento ordenado dos dados.

Você está planejando usar o `setPlaca` e `setModelo` mas quer inicializar o array com valores nulos. Isto não é possível, você precisa ter a instancia de um Veiculo em cada posição do array.

Ainda assim, creio que você esteja planejando ter o seguinte código. Primeiro, para simular o array com valores nulos:

```
// Simulando a inicialização de um array com valores nulos.
Veiculo[] estacionamento = new Veiculo[3];
estacionamento[0] = null;
estacionamento[1] = null;
estacionamento[2] = null;
```

E o código em questão:

```
for( int  i = 0; i < estacionamento.length;i++){

  if(estacionamento[i] == null){
    estacionamento[i] = new Veiculo(); //faltou instanciar Veiculo
    estacionamento[i].setPlaca(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("informe a placa do veiculo"));
    estacionamento[i].setModelo(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("informe o modelo do veiculo"));

  } else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " não ha vagas no estacionamento");
  } 
  break;
}
```

Comment: Setar valores nulos para cada posição é desnecessário, visto que um array de tipo não primitivo é inicializado com suas posições todas já nulas.

Comment: @StatelessDev, foi só para simular o caso dele. Não sei se ele tinha valores neste vetor antes, reaproveitando um vetor existente (não há esta parte do código disponível), então defini null para apenas para demonstração.

Comment: É exatamente esse raciocínio!....Realmente faltava instanciar o "Veiculo". Entretanto, agora ele me retorna a menssagem do else pra todas as vagas preenchidas, como resolvo essa questão para que a menssagem apareça apenas uma vez?  Um contador com um outro if resolveria?